# How to open a form on a separate thread due to language requirements

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, localization

I am using .NET 4.0. All of my forms have localization enabled and are translated into 3 languages.
I would like to open my main form, the one we run in program.cs, as a login form with a language button. Once the language is selected, since I cannot change the culture info of the current thread, I would like to open a new thread in the requested culture. What's the simplest way of doing that ?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you change the culture of the current thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-ca");
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this, it cannot work reliably by design.  The first obvious flaw you'll run into is that all the Windows dialogs won't change their language (MessageBox, OpenFileDialog, etc).  They always use the system language.  Much more serious are the non-obvious flaws.  You cannot control the culture of any threads easily, especially threadpool threads.  They'll do something nasty like fill a SortedList, a list that's isn't sorted anymore in the UI thread.  Many other subtle problems like this.

Moreover, it is a feature that no user ever needs.  They don't switch their mother tongue  on-the-fly.  If the machine really is used by multilingual users then it will have a version of Windows that allows switching the system language.  Your app automatically follows suit.

Comment: The feature is actually required for this specific program, since it is run in an environment with foreign workers who do not speak the national tongue.

Comment: I understand you concern about creating and managing threads. So, how would you do this? Thanks

Comment: There is no good solution for that.  .NET uses lots of TP threads that it creates itself.

Comment: @user592719: If the machine is used by foreign workers then just install the foreign language and turn it on.  Your app should NOT do this.

Answer (score 1):

`MyThread.CurrentUICulture = value;` You may read more [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture.aspx)